# How to simulate curl command with Angular

Tags: angularjs, http, authentication, post, curl

I have this curl command that I would like to simulate with angular:

```
curl -k -F fieldName=@data.json -u username:Password url
```

At the moment I went about doing an angular post. However, I run into the problem of authentication. There is no parameter for me to put the user id and password.

Angular code:

```
   $scope.postCall = function () {
        $scope.ngResult = "clicked";

        var paramsJson = {
            "imessageIdT": $scope.messageIdT,
            "ilobT": $scope.lobT,
            "iregionIdT": $scope.regionIdT,
            "iassetClassT": $scope.assetClassT,
            "additionalInfoT": $scope.additionalInfoT

        };

      var config = {
        paramsJson: paramsJson
      };

      $http.post("WEBSITE", paramsJson, config)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config)
        {
          $scope.ngResult = logResult("POST SUCCESS", data, status, headers, config);
          //$scope.ngResult = "Yes";
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config)
        {
          $scope.ngResult = logResult("POST ERROR", data, status, headers, config);

          //$scope.ngResult = "No";
        });


    };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Curl in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839170/how-to-use-curl-in-javascript)

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv is there no implementation in angular?

Comment: Why would there be one? AngularJS is a JavaScript framework. Anything written in JavaScript for the browser will work. This task is as much AngularJS related as it is Backbone or NodeJS. The only AngularJS thing you need to do after using the library in that answer is to `$scope.$apply` when you get the response, just like `$http` does.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming basic authentication, not tested, this might work:

```
var username = "...", password = "***";
var config = {
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic " + window.btoa(username+":"+password)
    },
    method: "get", // or "post",
    url: "destination.com"
};

$http(config).success(function(){
    // on success
}).error(function(){
    // on failure
});
```

The only thing I'm not certain about is `window.btoa`, if it's an RFC2045-MIME compliant variant of Base64, then you're good.

But my example is an over-simplification. Essentially, you should determine the authentication scheme supported by the server. It could be any one the following specified by [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml):

- Basic
- Bearer
- Digest
- HOBA
- Negotiate
- OAuth

Depending on the required scheme, you should compose the request header accordingly.

Comment: would you also put paramsJson:paramsJson inside config?

Comment: It would help you if you had a look at the angular documentation of $http, *the API does **not** make any mention of a property named paramJson*. If you're making a GET request consider specifying the request data by use of the `param` property. But if you're making a POST request, then the  `data` property would be more appropriate. What you probable want is  something like this: `config = { /* ... */ param: {name: "some-name", age: 44 }};`.

Comment: The above answer by @IgweKalu is the correct answer.  To make my AngularJS call a bit more friendly though I did the var userPass = window.btoa(username":"password) out side promise and just based that var to: { ... Authorization: 'Basic + userPass'}

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the api you are connecting to. Usually you would log and the server will return you an authentication token on the headers of the response.
1 Basic auth `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==`
2 Aoth2 `Authorization: Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM`

So you will need to add this header to your request:

```
 $http.post("WEBSITE", paramsJson, angular.extend({}, config, {headers: {
    'Authorization': token}}))
```

If the request is to another domain you should use jsonp.